# ti.cloudpush crash on Android M

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm having issues where Android apps that uses the ti.cloudpush module crash upon startup. Reporting this shows this information in Google dashboard:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.ingelby.faultfixersSAAS-1/lib/arm/libti.cloudpush.so: has text relocations
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:132)
    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:99)
    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:185)
    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)
```

I'm using 5.1.1GA and 3.4.0 of the ti.cloudpush module.

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: OK I fixed it. I grabbed 3.4.1 of ti.cloudpush module and that resolved the issue.

Comment: could you answer your own question so you can accept and others can up-vote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug of 5.1.1GA. You should update to 5.1.2GA.